# Evaluating C binary operations

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators

I am doing some logic tasks in C and while I evaluate by hand some of the results are different than the ones printed by CodeBlocks.

What is the decimal value of following expressions taking previously executed instructions into account?

Here're the numbers (I do not understand output of lines signed with "<<<<<<<<"):

```
int i, j, k, *p2i;

float fp;

p2i=&k;

i=0x22;

j=025;

k=25;

++k;

k++;

k|7&12;         <<<<<

fp=10/20;           <<<<<<

fp=(float)10/20;     <<<<<<
```

Comment: You don't understand 3 of 16 operations; is it really necessary to include the 13 you do understand in your question?

Comment: This is unnecessarily cryptic and hard to follow.  (What did you cut and paste it from?) Please show just the expressions you don't understand, say what you expected them to give, and what you got instead.

Comment: Possible things to be aware of:  & has higher precedence that |, integer division gives an integer result .

Comment: I have to evaluate decimal value on each line as the code follows. That's why that many.

Comment: @mjrdnk if you don't understand why, for example, p21, i, and j's assignments are 100% irrelevant to the entries you indicate you need help with, the problem is a little deeper than you think. The same is true for the entries regarding k after the entry of k you say you don't understand.

Comment: `fp=10/20;` does `int` divide before assigning the result to `float` ==> `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k=25;
++k;
k++;
k|7&12;
```

After the first 3 lines, `k` is 27.  In the fourth expression, the bitwise AND operator `&` has higher precedence than the bitwise OR operator `|`, so it is equivalent to `27|(7&12);`  Converting the values to binary gives us `11011|(00111&01100);`  The inner part evaluates to `00100`, then `11011|00100` evaluates to `11111`, which is 31.

The value of this expression appears in a `void` context (i.e. it isn't assigned to anything) and gets discarded.

```
fp=10/20;
```

The constants `10` and `20` are both of type `int`.  So integer division is performed, which results in 0.  That value is then cast to `float` and assigned to `fp`.

```
fp=(float)10/20;
```

The constant `10` is casted to `float`, then divided by `20`.  Since one of the operands is of type `float`, the other is promoted to than type and floating point division is performed, resulting in `0.5`.  That value is then assigned to `fp`.

Comment: thank you so much @dbush
Instead of 11011 for the outer value I have been calculating 11000.

Answer (score 3):

```
k|7&12;  ==>  27|7&12  ==> 27|4  ==> 31  (discarded value)

fp=10/20;  ==>  fp=0    ==>  0   (fp is now 0.0)

fp=(float)10/20;  ==>  fp=10.0f/20 ==>   fp=0.5f   (fp is 0.5)
```